# how to define model,controller,helper,block,layout.xml in config,xml file in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I m creating module for new product.....
I m creating this for my knowledge...

I wrote config.xml......
I also add mymodue_module.xml in etc of magento for my module....It is also showing in backend of magento

I wrote my controller.....

Bt when I called from by url it is showing error...

### my config.xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <!-- module configuration -->
    <modules>
        <Packt_New>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Packt_New>
    </modules>
    <!-- module configuration end -->
    <global>

        <blocks>
            <new>
                <class>

                    Packt_New_Block
                </class>
            </new>

        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <new>
                <class>
                    Packt_New_Helper
                </class>
            </new> 
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <new>
                <class>
                    Packt_New_Model
                </class>
            </new>
        </models>
    </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <new>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>
                            Packt_New
                        </module>
                        <frontName>
                            new
                        </frontName>  
                    </args>
                </new>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

my Controller..

---

```
<?php 

class Packt_New_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction(){



    }

    public function newAction(){


        echo "this is my new controller ";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use spaces or new lines in the tags that contain string values.
For example this:

```
            <class>
                Packt_New_Model
            </class>
```

Should be

```
<class>Packt_New_Model</class>
```

Do the same for all your config.xml file. Magento does not strip the value before using it.